# MySQL REGEXP: matching blank entries

Tags: mysql, regex

I have this SQL condition that is supposed to retrieve all rows that satisfy the given regexp condition:

```
country REGEXP ('^(USA|Italy|France)$')
```

However, I need to add a pattern for retrieving all blank country values. Currently I am using this condition

```
country REGEXP ('^(USA|Italy|France)$') OR country = ""
```

How can achieve the same effect without having to include the OR clause?

Thanks,
Erwin

Answer (score 6):

There's no reason you can't use the `$` (match end of string) to fill in your "empty subexpression" issue...

It looks a little weird but `country REGEXP ('^(USA|Italy|France|$)$')` will actually work

Comment: Thanks for the hint, fortunately it worked for my case too! But it's still strange that MySQL gets so hung up on "empty (sub)expressions", while other regex engines have no problem with them. I wonder if there's any reason for this?! (Yeah, I know this question is 13 years old, but I'm still curious)

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
country REGEXP ('^(USA|Italy|France|)$')
```

However from a performance point of view, you may want to use the IN syntax

```
country IN ('USA','Italy','France', '')
```

The later should be faster as REGEXP can be quite slow.

Comment: I have already tried adding the extra |, but it gave me this error:

"Got error 'empty (sub)expression' from regexp"

Comment: When I tried changing the expression to "country REGEXP ('^(USA|Italy|France|[\s]*)$')", it worked. Any issue with this approach?

@Ben btw I need to use REGEXP for this, because there are times when I need to use a pattern instead of the actual country name.

Comment: @Erwin: The only issue with `\s*` is that it will match 'blank' entries such as 3 spaces. If you don't have entries like this in your database, then it should be fine.

Comment: @eagle I'm not sure how the data in the database will look like. If not cleaned up properly, probably there will be blank data with 2 or more spaces. So if that's the case, maybe it would be safer to use the \s, right?

Comment: @Erwin: it all depends on you and your specific case if you want to consider an empty string and a string with spaces as the same or not. See my updated answer below for a solution for both of these situations, and choose the one that's right for you.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
country REGEXP ('^(USA|Italy|France|)$')
```

I just added another `|` after `France`, which should would basically tell it to also match `^$` which is the same as `country = ''`.

**Update:** since this method doesn't work, I would recommend you use this regex:

```
country REGEXP ('^(USA|Italy|France)$|^$')
```

Note that you can't use the regex: `^(USA|Italy|France|.{0})$` because it will complain that there is an empty sub expression. Although `^(USA|Italy|France)$|^.{0}$` would work.

Here are some examples of the return value of this regex:

```
select '' regexp '^(USA|Italy|France)$|^$'
> 1
select 'abc' regexp '^(USA|Italy|France)$|^$'
> 0
select 'France' regexp '^(USA|Italy|France)$|^$'
> 1
select ' ' regexp '^(USA|Italy|France)$|^$'
> 0
```

As you can see, it returns exactly what you want.

If you want to treat blank values the same (e.g. 0 spaces and 5 spaces both count as blank), you should use the regex:

```
country REGEXP ('^(USA|Italy|France|\s*)$')
```

This will cause the last row in the previous example to behave differently, i.e.:

```
select ' ' regexp '^(USA|Italy|France|\s*)$'
> 1
```

Comment: You know, you could have just used `^$` instead of `^.{0}$` on the Right Hand Side of the outer `|`

Comment: @gnarf: woops, I was trying so hard to avoid using look-arounds that I overlooked these simple solutions you provided. Thanks, I updated the answer.